# exporting into the same module from different files

Tags: typescript

Is is possible to export into the same module form 2 different typescript files?

I have:

### core/a1.ts

```
module a1 {
    export module a2 {
        export module Topic1 {
            export class Type1 {
                constructor(public id: string) { }
            }
            export let Entity = new Type1("entity");
        }
    }
}
```

### rel/b1.ts

```
module a1 {
    module a2 {
        module  Topic1 {
            // how do I export something into a1.a2.Topic1 ?
            export let Relation = new a1.a2.Topic1.Type1("relation");
        }
    }
    function test1() {
        // this works:
        let v1 = a1.a2.Topic1.Entity;

        // this show an error: 
        // Property 'Relation' does not exist on type 'typeof Topic1'.
        let v2 = a1.a2.Topic1.Relation;
    }
}
```

I've tried a few different approaches but could not get it to work.

The idea is here to use the top level module to distinguish between projects, and the inner/sub-modules for actual project modules and submodules. Is there a best practise when it comes to using typescript in large projects? Thanks.

EDIT 1: Updated the comment to reflect the intention - to export into the Topic1 rather than its parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simplified sample of your desire:

```
module a1 {
    export module a2 {
        export module Topic1 {
            // how do I export something into a1.a2 ?
        }
    }
}
```

Simple answer: No. You cannot export into `a1.a2` unless you are in `a1.a2`. In your case you are in `a1.a2.Topic1`.

## Update

> how do I export something into a1.a2.Topic1

Just make sure you export *every* level inside `a1`

```
module a1 {
    export module a2 {  // export here
        export module Topic1 {  // export here
            export const foo = 123;f // export here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for catching the mistake. The comment should have said: "how do I export something into a1.a2.Topic1 ?" I've updated the question to reflect it.

Comment: @sfeher cheers. I'd just like to warn you on the hazards of using *namespaces* and not a true module system : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/out.md